# R Selenium getPageSource() Not Returning Source

Tags: r, selenium, web-scraping

Morning far smarter than me peoples, I'm having some odd issues web-scraping Mashable.com which I hope someone can shed some light upon.

Mashable's search page populates the results from a  block looking something like...

```
    <script>
  window.__bootstrap = {"posts":[{"_id":"54b687d512d2cd49040027dd","id":"2015/01/14/bitcoin-price-200","title":"Bitcoin prices collapse below $200 for first time since 2013","title_tag":null,"author":"Seth Fiegerman","post_date":"2015-01-14T15:14:19+00:00","post_date_rfc":"Wed, 14 Jan 2015 15:14:19 +0000","sort_key":"1ybqcU","link":"http://mashable.com/2015/01/14/bitcoin-price-200/","content":{"plain":"Bitcoin prices are collapsing almost as quickly as they originally skyrocketed.
```

My usual technique for overcoming such post-render issues is to use Selenium to grab the page however today things are not going to plan.

With the URL http://mashable.com/search/?t=stories&q=bitcoin&page=2 loaded through Selenium

```
 remoteSelenium$navigate(uri) # send selenium to page
 html <- unlist(remoteSelenium$getPageSource()) # read in page contents
```

I get...

```
> html

               applicationCacheEnabled                              rotatable                          handlesAlerts                        databaseEnabled                                version 
                                "TRUE"                                "FALSE"                                 "TRUE"                                 "TRUE"                               "34.0.5" 
                              platform                           nativeEvents                         acceptSslCerts             webdriver.remote.sessionid                      webStorageEnabled 
                                 "MAC"                                "FALSE"                                 "TRUE" "ed06539a-59dc-41a5-ba4e-07b2ed9a9490"                                 "TRUE" 
                locationContextEnabled                            browserName                        takesScreenshot                      javascriptEnabled                    cssSelectorsEnabled 
                                "TRUE"                              "firefox"                                 "TRUE"                                 "TRUE"                                 "TRUE"
```

... rather than the page source itself.  Can't fathom why or how to resolve this as it works fine everywhere else I've tried it.  Any thoughts or pointers to other questions/answers?

Comment: thank you for reporting this. There was an issue with the mapping of unicode characters. Please try installing the latest dev version: `devtools::install_github("ropensci/RSelenium")` and retry your code.

Comment: Awesome John.  That fixed it perfectly.  Not sure what Mashable had done to their site over Christmas but with the dev RSelenium it scrapes again.  Yay!