# RSelenium: Not able to run example code

Tags: r, rselenium

I am new to `RSelenium`, and am having trouble with the following example from the "Introduction Vignette":

```
remDr$navigate("http://www.r-project.org")  # Works
webElem <- remDr$findElement("partial link text", "download R")  # Works
webElem$getElementText()  # Works
remDr$mouseMoveToLocation(webElement = webElem)  # DOES NOT Work!
```

I get the following error:

```
Error:   Summary: InvalidElementState
     Detail: An element command could not be completed because the element is in an invalid state (e.g. attempting to click a disabled element).
     class: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException
```

Any ideas?
I am running Firefox on Mac OS X with R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10).
EDIT:
Also does not work on R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09).

Answer (score 2):

```
library(RSelenium)
startServer()
# remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "chrome")
remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("http://www.r-project.org")  # Works
webElem <- remDr$findElement("partial link text", "download R")  # Works
webElem$getElementText()  # Works
```

checking versions:

```
> remDr$getStatus()$build
$version
[1] "2.45.0"

$revision
[1] "5017cb8"

$time
[1] "2015-02-26 23:59:50"

> remDr$sessionInfo$version
[1] "36.0.1"
```

running:

```
remDr$mouseMoveToLocation(webElement = webElem)  # DOES NOT Work!
```

replicates the error

Checking error messages:

```
remDr$value$localizedMessage
[1] "Cannot perform native interaction: Could not load native events component.\nBuild info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50'\nSystem info: host: 'JACK2', ip: '192.168.59.3', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_25'\nDriver info: driver.version: unknown"
```

we see that the `moveToLocation` method requires nativeEvents. Checking the [CHANGELOG](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/CHANGELOG) for selenium server version 2.45.0 we see:

> ## v2.45.0
>
> Important changes in this release:
>
> - Native events in Firefox relied on an API that Mozilla no longer provides. As such, fall back to synthesized events on recent Firefox
>     versions.

Methods requiring native events are currently not functional for the most recent version of firefox (36) and selenium server (2.45.0)

Comment: Many thanks. So seems like this will work in another browser. Let me try!

Comment: The chrome browser is not even opening!

Comment: Thanks @jdharrison. This is exactly what I am doing. In fact that's the page I was looking just now.

Comment: I just noticed your comment here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27963006/r-selenium-getpagesource-not-returning-source). So just going to try that now.