# error when installing package using 'devtools' in R

Tags: r, devtools, install.packages, rselenium

I try to install the package `RSelenium`:

```
devtools::install_github("ropensci/RSelenium")
```

This gives me following error:

```
Downloading GitHub repo ropensci/RSelenium@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/ropensci/RSelenium/zipball/master
Installing RSelenium
Error: Found continuation line starting '  <!DOCTYPE html PUB ...' at begin of     record.
```

Some research thaught me that I can simple install it using

```
install.packages("RSelenium, type="Source").
```

This indeed successfully installs the package, but gives trouble when using the function `getPageSource()` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27963006/r-selenium-getpagesource-not-returning-source).

EDIT: I'd also like to add that before the package installed successfully, but at one point it suddenly kept on failing.

Comment: I can install the package from GitHub without error messages. What version of `devtools` are you using? Mine is 1.10.0.

Comment: Mine also. Indeed, other programmers do not seem to have this problem. There must be something wrong on my laptop.